# how to add header and footer in doc with pywin32?

Tags: python, header, footer, pywin32, doc

i know how to get header and footer from word doc but what i am trying to do is manipulate those header and footer(like add more text or remove the existing text from header or footer). My question is how can i manipulate header and footer using python program and pywin32 ? please list some methods so that i can manipulate the header and footer.
Thank you in advance.

```
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("a.docx")
doc = word.ActiveDocument
footer = doc.sections[0].footers[0]    #get footer
header = doc.sections[0].headers[0]    #get header
print(str(header)+" "+str(footer))    #printing both
```

output:
header footer

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Keep in mind that depending on what you need,formatting may need adjustment.

```
doc = word.ActiveDocument       
sections = doc.Sections
for section in sections:

    headersCollection = section.Headers

    for header in headersCollection:
        header.Range.Text = header.Range.Text + "hello world"
        print(header.Range.Text)
```

Comment: What about the footer? Would that work the same way? Please edit your answer to include that